# Holonomic constraint forces using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: mechanical-engineering, modeling, dynamics, robotics

Consider a multibody robotic system with Lagrangian $$ L =\frac{1}{2} \dot{q}^{T}M\dot{q} - V $$ and equations of motion of the form
$$M(q)\ddot{q}+C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+A^{T}(q)\lambda+N(q)=0 $$

where $N=\frac{\partial V(q)}{\partial q}$  and $\lambda$ represents the Lagrange multipliers for the constraint forces (MLS pg. 269; pg. 287 in pdf). $A$ is the constraint matrix from the Pfaffian form $A\dot{q}=0$. We are concerned with **holonomic** constraints, which can be differentiated to obtain the Pfaffian form.
$ C=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \Gamma_{ijk}  \dot{q_{k}} $ where $\Gamma_{ijk}$ are the Christoffel symbols of the first kind.

The Lagrange multipliers can be calculated using the formula (MLS pg. 270, pg. 288 in pdf)
$$\lambda =-(AM^{-1}A^{T})^{-1}AM^{-1}(C\dot{q}-N)$$

This gives the holonomic constraint forces $A^{T}\lambda$.

**I would like to see some examples of this method for calculating the holonomic constraint forces for planar systems.**

I have seen this method being applied to calculate the tension in a simple pendulum (MLS pg. 270, pg. 288 in pdf), but I would like to see examples of **planar** systems with more degrees of freedom.

I'm specifically interested in the case of a 2R manipulator shown below.

[image: Planar 2R manipulator]

The equations of motion are on pg. 164-165 (pg. 182-183 in the pdf) in MLS.

My objectives are:

1. Apply the holonomic constraint $\theta_{1}(t)=0$ and obtain the holonomic constraint force.
2. Show that we get the dynamics of a simple pendulum for the
   constrained system for initial conditions $\theta_{2}(0)=0, \dot{\theta_{2}}(0)=0$.

I have done the calculation for the constraint $\theta_{1}(t)=0$ but I'm not able to show 2. The expression I get for $\lambda$ is

$$\lambda=
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{g (d \text{m2} \text{r2} (\sin  \text{t2})-\text{m2} \text{r2} (\cos  \text{t2}) ((\cos  \text{t2}) b+d))+b d (\sin  \text{t2}) \dot{\text{t2}} \dot{\text{t2}}}{d} \\
\end{array}
$$

where $(t1, t2)=(\theta_{1},\theta_{2})$ and $a, b, d$ are the geometric and inertial parameters $\alpha, \beta, \delta$ described in MLS (pg. 165; pg. 183 in the pdf).

Suggestions for other methods to calculate holonomic constraint forces would be helpful too.

***References:***

MLS refers to

> Murray, R. M., Li, Z., Sastry, S. S., & Sastry, S. S. (1994). [A
>   mathematical introduction to robotic manipulation](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/MLS/pdf/mls94-complete.pdf). CRC press.

Answer (score 1):

With multiple bodies it starts getting so complicated that I would forego doing it by hand and instead implement it in MATLAB or python using matrices. There are a few ways to do that (Lagrange isn't actually the most optimal one, as you're doing some unnecessary conversion to the energy domain), but it can be used. I could type out some equations, or post screenshots of my book. But my prof probably dos a far better job of explaining it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20v3XVnKP8k&t-27m25s